# Higher-dimensional reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reflection, root-systems

I would like to know if it is possible to find a hierarchy on reflections in the following sense:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional euclidean vector-space with standard inner product $\langle\, \_ \,,\, \_ \, \rangle$.

1. a 1-dimensional reflection should be the map $s:V \to V$, $v \mapsto -v$
2. a 2-dimensional reflection should be the map $V \to \text{Aut}(V)$, $v \mapsto \left(s_v: w \mapsto w-2 \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle v,v \rangle}v \right)$
3. I'm already not sure, what a 3-dimensional reflection should be, **but I would guess that the involved involution(s) $s$ now has(have) two indices**.
4. ...

Clearly, $s_v(v)=s(v)$, so I believe that $n$-dimensional reflection should be special cases of $n+1$-dimensional reflections

Sorry for this very vague question, I guess I'm counting on this being a well-known structure (if it exists) that is immediately recognized by someone who knows it..

**EDIT:** To avoid misunderstanding, $n$-dimensional reflections don't necessarily live in $n$-dimensional vector spaces. By an $n$-dimensional reflection I don't mean reflection through the hyperplane orthogonal to some vector, except for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact what you describe for dimension $2$, i.e. the map $V \to \text{Aut}(V)$, $v \mapsto \left(s_v: w \mapsto w-2 \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle v,v \rangle}v \right)$ is the general way to describe a reflection in any dimension.

You'll see that taking $v=1$ gives you what you describe for dimension equal to $1$.

And see this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions) for higher dimensions.

Comment: Thx! I actually don't mean reflection through the hyperplane orthogonal to some vector for higher $n$. Note that I didn't fix the dimension of $V$. I think I need to make more precise what I mean, sorry!

Comment: @BipolarMinds I may be wrong, but my understanding is that a reflection is an isometry with a hyperplane as a set of fixed points. Do you in fact want to deal with orthogonal symmetries?

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my last comment, it was nonsense. I have to think a bit more about the analogy

Comment: I think what I want for $(n=3)$ a map $(v,w) \mapsto s_{v,w}$, so that $s_{v,w}$ is reflection through the $(dimV-2)$-dim hyperplane orthogonal to the span of $v$ and $w$. Does this always uniquely exist? I just convinced myself for $dimV=3$.

Comment: It's a bit weird that for $n=3$, the fixed point dimension is $(dimV-2)$, for $n=2$ its $dimV-1$ but for $n=1$ its $0$.. maybe, I should take $s=id$.